# deploying a rails app with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

when executing: `cap production deploy:initial`

I get an error message:

```
** Execute deploy:assets:precompile
00:08 deploy:assets:precompile
    /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
    rake aborted!
    LoadError: cannot load such file -- single_test/tasks

    /home/deploy/apps/A_W_Creamery/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:i…
```

Comment: It raises error while running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, you can debug it locally.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like, you previously have installed [Single test](https://github.com/grosser/single_test) gem and now you remove it, but you forgot to remove command:

```
require 'single_test/tasks'
```

from your **Rakefile**.